# Meaning of the angle brackets in a specific context

Tags: lasso

I'm (hoping to) follow along with an implementation of coordinate descent for multivariate lasso that's written up [here](http://jocelynchi.com/a-coordinate-descent-algorithm-for-the-lasso-problem). However, the author's notation loses me a bit. In particular, I'm unsure of what the angle bracket in the statement

$$\frac{1}{2n}⟨r_k - \beta_k x_k, r_k - \beta_kx_k ⟩ + \lambda ||\beta||_1$$

...mean.

This appears almost at the beginning, very near the problem formulation.

Comment: Hard to guess because it's not defined the blog post. Have you tried emailing the author?

Comment: I would be mightily surprised if the author managed to invent a notation capable of confounding the minds on Stat Exchange. As is the math that follows seems incomprehensible. I don't suppose you have a better source to read on implementing this algorithm? Haha.

Comment: angle brackets are used to denote the inner product (dot product in this case)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The angle brackets $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$ appear to be the Euclidean ($L^2$) inner product. You can see  via the identity $||x||_2^2 = \langle x, x \rangle$ and by comparing with the preceding line:

$$f(\beta) = \frac{1}{2n} ||r_k - \beta_k x_k||^2_2 + \lambda ||\beta||_1 \\= 
\frac{1}{2n}⟨r_k - \beta_k x_k, r_k - \beta_kx_k ⟩ + \lambda ||\beta||_1$$

Comment: looks like you meant to say squared distance and $<x,x> = \|x\|_2^2$?